# How to find the DRBL verison?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, clonezilla

I tried below commands,

```
sudo drbl -v
sudo drblsrv -v
sudo drblsrv --version
```

but they didn't work!

Sorry, there are no tags for **drbl**, so I tagged **clonezilla**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the installed packages on your Ubuntu system and display only the lines containing `drbl`

```
user@ubuntu:/home/user# sudo apt list --installed | grep drbl


drbl/bionic,bionic,now 2.20.11-4 all [installed]
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see other application's version also using apt list.